# Starting advice for data-trawling routine

Tags: c++

I'm looking for some general advice on the most efficient way to go about creating a data-trawling routine. I have a basic knowledge of C++.

I need to create a routine to search through a text file which has the following format (example):

```
4515397   404.4    62.5  1607.0     2.4     0.9 ...
4515398   404.4    62.3  1607.0     3.4     1.2 ...
4515399   404.4    62.2  1608.0     4.6     0.8 ...
4515400   405.1    62.2  1612.0     5.8     0.2 ...
4515401   405.9    62.2  1615.0     6.9    -0.8 ...
4515402   406.8    62.2  1617.0     8.0    -2.7 ...
4515403   406.7    62.1  1616.0     9.0    -5.3 ...
```

In the above example, I am interested in exporting the **average values of columns 2 and 3, when columns 5 and 6 are both less than 4**. I am not actually interested in the values in columns 1, 4 or 7 (the ellipses are exactly how they appear in the file itself).

To further complicate matters, occasionally random strings of text appear in the file, like this (these can be thrown away):

```
4522787   429.6    34.4  2024.0    .       .    ...
4522788   429.9    34.2  2022.0    .       .    ...
4522789   429.9    34.1  2022.0    .       .    ...
EFIX R   4522633    4522789 157   427.9    36.8    2009
4522790   429.3    34.2  2021.0    .       .    ...
END 4522791     SAMPLES EVENTS  RES   23.91   23.82
MSG 4522799 TRIAL_RESULT 0
MSG 4522799 TRIAL OK
```

Finally, each text file contains five sets of data in which I intend on averaging up the values. Each of these 5 data sets are bounded by lines like this:

```
MSG 4502281 START_GRAB
```

and

```
MSG 4512283 END_GRAB
```

Everything outside these bounds can be thrown away.

So, as a relatively inexperienced programmer, I'm starting to look at the most efficient ways of achieving objectives. What would be my best approach; i.e. is C++ needlessly complicated for this sort of task? Perhaps there is even a utility already available that can do this sort of data-trawling?

It just occurs to me now that I could potentially use a Microsoft Excel script to do this for me. I'd like to know any thoughts on this.

Comment: I would do this in python, or a similar scripting language, rather than C++.

Comment: You can use the "awk" tool to accomplish this.

Comment: The tools I can use are C++, Excel or MATLAB. Anything else would probably (I presume) involve more time to learn than writing this in C++ would take

Comment: Scripting languages are good, except if the input data is huge. If you need to do that in C++, consider using a parser generator like ANTLR

Comment: `sed 's/[A-Z]//g'` or `tr -d A-Z` for prefiltering. and yes, this task begs for `awk`.

Comment: When a line has a random bit of text and data, like line #4 in your second example, does the whole line get thrown away? (Excepting, of course, the `START_GRAB` and `END_GRAB` lines.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with the naive approach and see how far I'd get:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
  if (!infile) { return 0; }

  std::vector<double> v2, v3;

  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(infile, line))
  {
    int id;
    double col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6;
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    if (iss >> id >> col1 >> col2 >> col3 >> col4 >> col5 >> col6)
    {
       // we only get here if the first token is an integer!

       if (col5 < 4.0 && col6 < 4.0)
       {
         v2.push_back(col2);
         v3.push_back(col3);
       }
    }
    else
    {
      iss.clear(); // clear error
      std::string id;
      if (iss >> id && id == "MSG")
      {
        // process the special block
      }
    }
  }

  // now compute the average of the v2 and v3:
  double av2 = std::accumulate(v2.begin(), v2.end(), 0) / double(v2.size());
  double av3 = std::accumulate(v3.begin(), v3.end(), 0) / double(v3.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it with C++, I strongly recommend [Boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)

Basically, you need three regular expressions: The one for START_GRAB, one for the payload lines and one for the END_GRAB line. Writing regular expressions is not too hard. There are many tutorials online, and you can try your regular expressions here:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/